# An isekai manga where the FMC is isekai'd into a noble body?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga a long time ago, and the website that had it had shut down so now I'm looking for it.

I think the main character isekai'd into a otome game that she plays a lot, just to interact with the side character, the ML, which is her favorite.

She's quiet OP, like most of the isekai manga MCs.

The ML is a son of a merchant, I think. They met each other when the MC's family was buying a lot of stuff from oversea? for MC's siblings.

ML was watching the ants working when the MC approached and proposed right there. (it was funny af so I remember)
The ML is the closed eyes type.

I think the ML's family was being compared to the dragon?? by the rumours(I think it was because they are overprotective of their 'treasure').

Anw I remember them saving the prince from a curse, after kidnapping him at the damn tea party.. (The prince's mom is a rank A adventurer)

And the ML is kinda overpowered too.

MC isekai'd into a noble child.

That's all I can remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? And do you recall the hair colour of the main characters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is *The Villainess Wants to Marry a Commoner*.

The main character, Isabella, is reincarnated into the world of an otome game as the villainess, and her favorite character in the game, Ursch, was the merchant that showed up when rolling the gatcha.

After reincarnating, the two meet while Ursch was watching ants when his family went to Isabella's house so her father could buy a present for his eldest daughter.  His family was sometimes called Fafnir's Kin, referring to a poisonous dragon who horded gold. Ursch himself is the closed eyes type.

Midway through the series, Isabella goes to the prince's tea party and ends up kidnapping the prince after realizing he can hear the thoughts of everyone within 5km. After the prince is told that, he vows to train the skill so he can control it.

Comment: Omg thank you so much!!